# Flutter removeInvalidNode jank list is null

Tags: flutter

i am creating the elearing app using flutter.while creating app after i was testing i got the problem was
full stacktrace i attached below. i have add the widget for source display of flutter markdowndown.if i click the particular lession according to the code snippet would display that what i need.but when i click the course i go the error was i attached below.what i tried so far i attached below.

```
W/Gralloc3( 5767): mapper 3.x is not supported E/        ( 5767): APS:IFLoad:importExternalFunctions, search function createNewHwApsUtils failed, dlsym err:undefined symbol: createNewHwApsUtils D/        ( 5767): APS:importExternalFunctions OK I/HwViewRootImpl( 5767): removeInvalidNode jank list is null D/AwareBitmapCacher( 5767): handleInit switch not opened pid=5767 W/Settings( 5767): Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global
```

**list.dart**

```
    ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: baglist.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) => Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Code(
                                        size: size,
                                        bagModel: baglist[i],
                                      )));
                        },
                        child: ProductCard(
                          size: size,
                          name: baglist[i].name,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

**bagModel.dart**

```
    import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
    
    class Bagmodel {
      final int id;
    
      final String name;
      final String code;
      Bagmodel({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.code,
      });
    }
    
    List<Bagmodel> baglist = [
      Bagmodel(id: 1, name: "Java", code: """
```

```
#  Java Introduction


  ---
  This is a simple Markdown test. Provide a text string with Markdown tags
  to the Markdown widget and it will display the formatted output in a
  scrollable widget.
  
  ## Section 1
  Maecenas eget **arcu egestas**, mollis ex vitae, posuere magna. Nunc eget
  aliquam tortor. Vestibulum porta sodales efficitur. Mauris interdum turpis
  eget est condimentum, vitae porttitor diam ~~ornare~~. [eclectify](www.eclectify.com)
  

  > class HelloWorld 
  >  {
  >  public static void main(String[] args) {
  >      System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
  >  }
  >  }


>  String name =txtname.getText();
>  String age =txtmobile.getText();
>  String course =txtcourse.getText();
>        try {
>            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Register the mysql driver
>            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/linda","root","");
>            insert = con1.prepareStatement("insert into record (name,mobile,course)values(?,?,?)");
>            insert.setString(1,name);
>            insert.setString(2,age);
>            insert.setString(3,course);
>            insert.executeUpdate();
>           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Saved");                        
>            txtname.setText("");
>            txtmobile.setText("");
>            txtcourse.setText("");
>            table_update();
>        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
>            Logger.getLogger(crud.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
>        } catch (SQLException ex) {
>            Logger.getLogger(crud.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
>        } 


  1. ajdsks
     1. this requires 3 spaces
     2. fdlefkl
  2. reorek
  3. fdpopore
 """),
  Bagmodel(id: 2, name: "C#", code: "saaaaaa"),
  Bagmodel(id: 3, name: "VB", code: "vvvvvvvvvvv"),
  Bagmodel(id: 4, name: "C", code: "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"),
  Bagmodel(id: 5, name: "Asp", code: "uiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii")
];
```

**Code.dart**

```
class Code extends StatelessWidget {
  const Code({
    super.key,
    required this.size,
    required this.bagModel,
  });

  final Size size;
  final Bagmodel bagModel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: buildAppBar(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Markdown(
            data: bagModel.code,
          ),
        ));
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      title: Text("Back"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
    );
  }
}
```